# Find the number of elements of order 2 and number of subgroups of index 2.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $A= \mathbb Z_{60} \oplus \mathbb Z_{45} \oplus \mathbb Z_{12} \oplus \mathbb Z_{36}$.
>
> 1) what is the number of elements in A with order 2.
>
> 2) what is the number of subgroups of A with index 2.

I don't understand the meaning of $\oplus$

If i'm not wrong the element of order 2 in $Z_{60}$ is 30,

in $Z_{45}$ there is none , $Z_{12}$ is 6 and $Z_{36}$ is 18.

how do I proceed from here?

about number 2 i don't know how to start solving it.

any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \oplus B$ means the direct sum of two groups $A$ and $B$. So
$$A \oplus B = \{(a,b) \, | \, a \in A, b \in B\}$$
and it inherits a group operation based on those of $A$ and $B$.

**Hint for part(1):**

In general if $(a,b) \in A \oplus B$, then the order $|(a,b)|=\text{lcm }(|a|, |b|)$. In your case you want this lcm to be $2$. Thus you will need to deal with some cases:

- $|a|=2,|b|=1$,
- $|a|=1,|b|=2$,
- $|a|=2,|b|=2$

Of course you will need to generalize this idea for your problem as you have more groups in the direct sum. Moreover if $d$ is a divisor of $n$, where $n$ is the order of the cyclic group, then number of elements of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$. This can help you with some calculations.

**Hint for part (2):**

Index $2$ subgroups $H$ are those for which there are only two cosets $H$ and $aH$ (where $a \not\in H$). In which case $a^2 \in H$.

I hope this will help you start exploring more into your problem.

Comment: just to make sure i understand correctly - in 1) the elements are : (30,0,0,0) , (30,0,0,18) , (30,0,6,0) , (30,0,6,18) , (0,0,6,0) , (0,0,6,18) , (0,0,0,18)?

Comment: didn't understand part 2. if I look only on $Z_{60}$ and i want to find subgroups of index 2 . If I understand your explanation then the cosets are $Z_2$ and $30Z_2$ ? but then 30^2 is 60 and is not in $Z_{60}$

Comment: @gpgpgp I had a typo for part 2, which I have fixed. $a^2 \in H$ (because $a^2 \in G$ is trivially true). For $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$. The subgroup $H=\langle 2 \rangle$ is of index $2$ (it is not $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as you have mentioned in your comment) . The cosets are $H$ and $1+H$, where $1+1 \in H$.